# Can not run node.js app with web client

Tags: node.js, browser

I wrote and ran a node.js program (eg: hello.js) on my linux server with IP Address 62.x.x.x with basic content:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(
    function(req,res){
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'Text plain'}); 
        res.end('Hello ');
    }
).listen(8000)
```

I tried to test it on the server with curl command: `curl http: //127.0.0.1:8000`

I got the expected result: `hello` on screen.

But when i tried it on my client machince with a browser client (IE, Firefox,...) `http://62.x.x.x:8000` the webbrowser can not load this page and can not return my result.

I don't know what does this error mean?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the firewall is stopping the page from loading. You need to configure your firewall to allow outbound traffic on port 8000

Comment: i only connect to my server through by SSH (putty or secure crt), so is there anyway to configure my firewall ? thank

Comment: I'm going to need a LOT more help than that to give you your answer. What sort of server? (I assume from SSH that it's a Linux distro, which one, etc) How is the firewall normally administered? Where is the server located? Who hosts it? What management interface do you have to it? Is it in a VM? Across the room? Under your desk?

Answer (score 1):

Try listeting to your external interface, like

```
).listen(8000, "62.x.x.x")
```